# How to Clean uninstall nodejs / node on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I had installed node and npm via :
`$sudo apt-get install npm`

then I realised the node version was 4.2.6, which I could not run my code ( some function syntax errors/ type erros etc.)

So I set to uninstall nodejs:

`sudo apt-get remove npm
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
sudo apt-get autoremove
rm -r /usr/local/bin/npm
rm  -rf  ~/.npm
rm -rf  /opt/local/bin/node
rm  -rf  opt/local/include/node
rm -rf /opt/local/lib/node_modules`

Installing again with latest LTS,
I am following install instructions from https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
 sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

My Question: After above install nodejs version is still 4.2.6, How can I get the latest version ? Or uninstall and clean the 4.2.6 ?

Comment: Use this command for uninstall and clean:  sudo apt-get remove <application_name> but this question stack overflow https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143/how-can-i-uninstall-software

Comment: This is specific to nodejs uninstall/install sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libuv1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libuv1 nodejs
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 203 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,161 kB/3,218 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 nodejs amd64 4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4.1 [3,161 kB]

Comment: @SamDev : this is very specific to nodejs and ubuntu and not "how to uninstall any package". I would appreciate if you can read the full question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install node using NVM (Node Version Manager)

Do this:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash
```

this will download and execute the NVM installation script. NVM should now be installed.

After that just use it to install node. Open a **new** terminal and for example do

```
nvm install 6.11.4
```

This installs node version 6.11.4, which is the latest LTS. You can install any version you want. Do

```
nvm ls-remote
```

to see all available versions and just replace the version number.

You can install any number of node versions, and switch between them using

```
nvm use 6.11.4
```

also you can set a default version using

```
nvm alias default 6.11.4
```

Comment: @Mina - Thanks, helped me out of a bind

Answer (score 0):

Go to [node.org](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) website

download binaries

unpack it

replace original files with unpacked content

for example

```
sudo mv ./bin/* /usr/bin/
sudo mv ./lib/* /usr/lib/
etc ...
```